# Adding Classnames to Style Dynamically Generated Content for Jquery UI Themes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Adding Classnames to Style Dynamically Generated Content for Jquery UI Themes

I have made a simple markdown display page template @ https://minjslib.github.io/gh-template/

I already have the jquery ui theme css added and some elements on the page already show it working. However, there is an Article Div that receives the dynamically generated html from the Textarea on the webpage. I tried the following

```
$( "Article" ).children().addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
```

[here is a permalink to the full source.](https://github.com/MinJSLib/gh-template/blob/963b2cd340c9ecddfe83f6277fc0f9075183fa6a/index.html#L30)

Comment: Sincerely wish there was a way to determine, which piece of down syndrome garbage down-voted this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be like this

```
$( "#Article" ).children().addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
```

Since it is an id of the div

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses css selectors. Try $('#Article') to reference an element by its id.